# I can't load animation and I can't remove it after request has been loaded

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, gif

I do some stuff on native part of my application. Then, when I get sessionID from my server, I set it to `WKWebView`. Then, I load my webpage to webview itself. The problem is, I used the function called "didfinish" for playing a gif. That function works, it is called everytime, however when I tried to stop gif, it says nil to my image view.

I put my imageview on top of a view, which covers the `WKWebview`, with that user won't see, a blank view till it's fully loaded.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...some code...
        imageViewForAnimation.loadGif(named:"gif")
        loadWeb()
}
func loadWeb(){
        setCookie()
        view=self.webview
        webview?.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: lastURL)!))
        self.webview.navigationDelegate=self
}
func setCookie(){
        print("session id is:\(session_id)")
        let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [
            .domain: "mywebpage.com",
            .path: "/",
            .name: "sessionID",
            .value: "\(session_id)",
            .secure: "TRUE",
            .expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 31556926)
            ])!
        let websitedataStorage=WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()
        websitedataStorage.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie) {
        }
        let configuration=WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.websiteDataStore=websitedataStorage
        webview=WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: configuration)
}
```

Everything works fine without any gif or without any additional stuff. What I want is, if page is ready

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
                 didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.imageViewForAnimation.image=nil   //for stopping animating
        self.coverViewOnTopOfWebView.alpha=0   //show web now

 }
```

The error that I get is

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly
>   unwrapping an Optional value

At the didFinish function. For playing gifs I used this class

https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif/blob/master/SwiftGifCommon/UIImage%2BGif.swift

Thank you guys for any help and advice in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making mistake in following code of `loadWeb()` method.

```
view=self.webview
```

Above code will set nil to all other control which are placed inside `view`. 
Instead of assigning `self.webView` to `view`, You should add it from storyboard or add it programatically in view like:

```
self.view.insertSubview(self.webview, at: 0)
```

Or

```
self.view.addSubview(self.webview)
```

which one is preferable to you.

Comment: Ooo, I see, but I already put WebView on the view at storyboard. If I don't use `view=self.webview` this line, it can't load the web, just empty. Nothing appears.

Comment: You can use other solution that I have added.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, it work with no problem when I add WebView as subview. In addition, for the ones who had same problem, I carried delegates(navigationdelegate, uidelegeta) after adding it subview. Otherview some functions of those delegates can't work properly.